# Access business classes from model classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, model, business-objects

I wonder if it's possible to access business objects from the model classes, and is it design clean ?

Comment: If by model, you're referring to a class/POJO that simply holds data, then the answers are yes, it's possible and no, it's not clean design. It looks (and in the long run, works) better if your model is not aware of the business logic/process surrounding it. A model class is going to be subjected to a wide variety of transformations and operations by numerous business processes over it's lifetime and it's simply unsustainable to continually modify the model to suit business operation needs. Try as much as possible to design your model to be busineess process agnostic

Comment: That's a good answer for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much depend from what you call model object and what you call business object.
If you operating model idiom from modern understanding of MVC pattern (like ASP.NET MVC for example, or spring), than probably business logic will be the part of the model and in such case you could do that of course =)

If you talked about model which is view-model itself, and it's only goal just to store the data to consume it with UI, then your model should be as dumb as possible. it should be prepared by someone from business logic and then transferred to UI and that's all.

And also if your application is really small, then first criteria will be how much it will simplify your life. Because doing small project like the big one will be over engineering for sure.